# Splitting an array into further arrays based on values

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi there i have an array of data that looks like this (it contains list number and brand name):

`["1_Sophie_Gray", "2_Atlantic_Bay", "2_Trait", "3_Tammy", "3_Flipback", "3_Duck_Dodge", "3_Bambini", "4_Bellisima"]`

What i need to do is separate these out and create a ul for each of the lists (1 is Womens clothing, 2 mens clothing, 3 childrens clothing and so on). I though the best way to do this was to loop through this array and separate the values into different arrays of their own based on the list number, e.g.

`["1_Sophie_Gray"]`

`["2_Atlantic_Bay", "2_Trait"]`

`["3_Tammy", "3_Flipback", "3_Duck_Dodge"]`

The reason i want to do this is to build a separate list of icons for each of these new arrays. So eventually i'll end up with this:

```
<div class="store_brands">
<p id="brand_intro">
    Brands and departments available in this store:
</p>
<h4>list 1</h4>
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="/images/v3/brand_logos/wallis.gif" alt="list 1 brands" />
    </li>
</ul>
<h4>list 2</h4>
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="/images/v3/brand_logos/atlantic_bay.gif" alt="list 2 brands" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="/images/v3/brand_logos/trait.gif" alt="list 2 brands" />
    </li>
</ul>
<h4>list 3</h4>
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="/images/v3/brand_logos/tammy.gif" alt="list 3 brands" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="/images/v3/brand_logos/flipback.gif" alt="list 3 brands" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="/images/v3/brand_logos/duck_dodge.gif" alt="list 3 brands" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my code:

```
function inStoreBrands (storeData) {

var brandsArr = [],
    listNum,
    fileName,
    brandImgsPath = "/images/v3/brand_logos/",      
    brandList = '<div class="store_brands"><p id="brand_intro">Brands and departments available in this store:</p>',
    brandResults = storeData.brands,
    brands = brandResults.split(", "),
    listCount = 1,
    titleText = "list 1";

        for (var i=0; i<brands.length; i++) {
            listNum = brands[i].split(/_(.+)/)[0];
            listNum = parseInt(listNum);

            fileName = brands[i].split(/_(.+)/)[1];
            fileName = fileName.toString().toLowerCase();

            function addToArray () {
                brandsArr.push(brandImgsPath + fileName + '.gif');
            }

            if(listNum !== listCount){
                buildBrandList(brandsArr, titleText);
                titleText = "list " + listNum;
                addToArray();
            } else {
                addToArray();
            }
        }

function buildBrandList(brandsArr, titleText) {
    brandList += '<h4>'+titleText+'</h4>';
    brandList += '<ul>';
    for (i=0; i < brandsArr.length; i++) {
        brandList += '<li><img src="'+brandsArr[i]+'" alt="'+titleText+' brands" /></li>';
    }
    brandList += '</ul>';
    brandsArr = [];
    listCount++;
}

brandList += '</div>';      
return brandList;               
};
```

I know the logic is horribly flawed, hence the reason it doesn't work. Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: What specifically doesn't work in your code?  It seems like you have the right idea, try to identify exactly what in your code or logic is broken and shorten your question to focus just on that.

Comment: Hi Maerics, i just read that back and you're right it could of been explained better. The problem i am having is filtering anything with a listNum of 1 from the brands array and storing it in its own array, then passing that to the buildBrandList function and creating the html for it. I then want to set brandsArr back to empty and to the same thing for anything with a listNum of 2 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post the exact data for storeData and how you built it - so I made some assumptions: [see the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TC7xB/)

Comment: Hi Mike, you are correct in your assumptions about storeData. As you can see the html output does not match up to the incoming data. So list 2 should only have 2 items, list 3 should only have 4 and list 4 has not even been created. Any ideas where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

A simple design change might help you out. Consider changing the format of how you create your brands array. For example, instead of storing  1_Sophie_Gray, consider 1_Sophie-Gray.

```
var arr1;
var arr2;
//etc

for(i=0;i<brands.length - 1; i++){ //So we've split 1_Sophie-Gray from everything else
   var tmpArr = brands[i].split('_');
   if(tmpArr[0] == 1){             //parse to the correct array
      arr1.push("brands[i]");      //push into the appropriate array
   } else if(tmpArr[0] == 2) {
      arr2.push("brands[i]");
   }
}
```

Keep in mind that this is psuedo-ish code. Hope that helps!

-sf

EDIT: To answer El Guapo's question in the comments. Yes, you can create the arr variables dynamically, but you will have to do so with a little bit of work from the code-behind side of things. All code behind examples are in VB.Net.

If you are wanting this function to be fired on page load. You can build and register it in the Page_Load function using the Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock method.
Example in Page_Load()

```
Protected Overrides Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
     If Not ScriptManager1.IsInAsyncPostBack Then
      MyBase.Page_Load(sender, e)
      'Do whatever else you need to do on Page Load

      Page.Form.DefaultButton = btnSubmit.UniqueID
      Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),createjs())

End Sub

Public Function createjs() As String
   Dim str As String = ""
   str = "<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>function ClickSubmit(){var btn = '" & btnSubmit.ClientID & "'; btn = getElementSomehow(btn); btn.click()};" & _
   " <all your javascript> " & _
   " //Im using & _ to make things more readable once the js gets created" & _
   " </script>"
   return str
End Function
```

Creating the javascript from the code behind allows you to pass in arrays to your client that wouldn't normally be available. Let's take the contrived example above, and get a little closer to what you'd like to do. Say arr is a variable you've got somewhere else and it's defined as follows:

```
arr = ""1_Sophie_Gray", "2_Atlantic_Bay", "2_Trait", "3_Tammy", "3_Flipback", "3_Duck_Dodge", "3_Bambini", "4_Bellisima""
```

Note that you could add, delete, modify this array entirely from the .vb code. Then, once it's where you want it. You can throw it to your code behind function that has been tasked with creating your client side javascript.

```
Public Function ModifyJS(ByVal PassedArr As String) As String
   Dim str As String = ""
   str = "<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>function ClickSubmit(){var btn = '" & btnSubmit.ClientID & "'; btn = getElementSomehow(btn); btn.click()};" & _
   " <all your javascript> " & _
   " var JSarr = [" & PassedArr & "]; " & _
   " //Im using & _ to make things more readable once the js gets created" & _
   " </script>"
   return str
End Function
```

And...then it's not a huge leap to get here:

```
Public Function ModifyJS(ByVal PassedArr As String, ByVal NoArrays As Integer) As String
   Dim str As String = ""
   str = "<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>function ClickSubmit(){var btn = '" & btnSubmit.ClientID & "'; btn = getElementSomehow(btn); btn.click()};" & _
   " <all your javascript> " & _
   " var JSarr = [" & PassedArr & "]; " & _
   For i As Integer = 0 To NoArrays
      str &= " var arr" & i & "=[];"
   Next
   " //Im using & _ to make things more readable once the js gets created" & _
   " </script>"
   return str
End Function
```

Hope that helps bro!

-sf

Comment: Hi sacredfaith, i have used your suggestion to solve the problem [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/kXUZc/22/) (don't know why that js fiddle isn't working, but you get the jist). 

However my problem is that i want it to be dynamic in the sense that i will not always know that there are going to be 5 lists to create. I know this is asking a lot, but is there a way to create the arr1, arr2 vars dynamically, and call the buildBrandList function in a loop for each of these arrays? Thanks